# Pandas: df.index.str.extract() not working like re.findall()

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to use `df.<column_name or index>.str.extract(r'\d+')` on the following:

```
28    USD-ABC-S__7y
29    USD-ABC-S__8y
Name: InstrumentIdentifier, dtype: object
```

This is giving me a ValueError though:

```
ValueError: pattern contains no capture groups
```

However, when I try:

```
import re
re.findall(r'\d+', 'USD-ABC-S__8y')
```

this returns the expected result: `[8]`

Any ideas why the Pandas version isn't giving the same result as re?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the regex in a capturing group (`(...)`):

```
df.<column_name or index>.str.extract(r'(\d+)')
```

Example:

```
df['InstrumentIdentifier'].str.extract(r'(\d+)', expand=False)
```

output:

```
28    7
29    8
Name: InstrumentIdentifier, dtype: object
```

Comment: that might be a new speed record answer for you @mozway!  Now I have to wait 12min to accept it! :)